# "Reset" Button for Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

I want to distribute a .cdf to my students wherein they manipulate 5 locators on a graph to define various shapes. The .cdf opens with the locators in a "nice" position, but of course it is very hard to return the locators, by hand, to these positions once they have been moved. Is there a way to utilize a "Reset" button that returns all settings to the original state? The only method I can see right now is to reopen the file in the CDFPlayer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your average `Manipulate` has the "Inital settings" button (which is just another bookmark):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another straightforward way would be a simple button to set certain values:

```
Manipulate[x, {{x, 5}, 0, 10}, Button["Reset", x = 5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which (as pointed out in the comments) allows for unlimited styling, for good or bad:

```
Manipulate[x, {{x, 5}, 0, 10}, 
 Button[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Black]], Red, Disk[], 
    Yellow, Style[Text["Don´t\n PANIC!", {0, 0}], Bold, 40]}], 
  x = 5, Background -> None]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I use the reset button method. More clear and you have more control on what to do there. Also for demo published at WRI web site, those options given in the menu above are not there. Only autorun is there.

Comment: I, too, like the Reset button better, as it is much more clear to the user. The built in `ResetButton` option also works, but isn't as clear as a big button that says "Reset."

Comment: @Nasser o.k. - I only tried with the CDF preview, which shows all elements. And yes, the `Button` method is rather more transparent, even if the bookmarks are very useful in some cases.

Comment: @GregH and of course, you can `Style` your `Button` however you wish...

Comment: @Nasser confirmed: the browser plugin does not offer the dropdown menu, while the downloaded CDF opened in Mathematica does.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard then this is one +1 I specially cherish :-)

Answer (score 15):

Just another way, using built-in functionality `ResetButton`:

```
Manipulate[x, {{x, 5}, 0, 10}, AppearanceElements -> "ResetButton"]
```

[image]

Comment: I just learned something. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard So this day was a good day :) I'm glad you did.