# TrackingFunction not working properly if range contains a mathematical constant

Tags: manipulate, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 11.1.1.0 or later**

---

Answering [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101650/18476) I had to realize that [`TrackingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackingFunction.html) isn't working properly if at least one value of the corresponding variable range is a [mathematical constant](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MathematicalConstants.html).

For example:

```
Manipulate[Column[{
   {a, b, c, d},
   {lasta, lastb, lastc, lastd}
   }],
 {a, 0, Pi, TrackingFunction -> {lasta = a; &, a = #; &, a = #; &}},
 {b, 0, N[Pi], TrackingFunction -> {lastb = b; &, b = #; &, b = #; &}},
 {c, 0, GoldenRatio, TrackingFunction -> {lastc = c; &, c = #; &, c = #; &}},
 {d, Pi, N[2. Pi], TrackingFunction -> {lastd = d; &, d = #; &, d = #; &}},
 {{lasta, 0}, None}, {{lastb, 0}, None}, {{lastc, 0}, None}, {{lastd, 0}, None}]
```

[image: ScreenGIF]

Note that only `lastb` gets updated properly in this example and `TrackingFunction` fails to update `lasta`, `lastc`, and `lastd`.

Is this a bug?
What workarounds other than applying [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) to the mathematical constants are there?

---

Replacing the first `TrackingFunction` with

```
TrackingFunction -> {lasta = N@a; &, a = N@#; &, a = N@#; &}
```

doesn't solve the problem.

---

Using the second argument of `Dynamic` within a `Manipulator` seems to work correctly.

```
DynamicModule[{n, m = 0},
 {Manipulator[Dynamic[n, {m = n; &, n = #; &, n = #; &}], {0, Pi}], Dynamic[n], Dynamic[m]}]
```

[image]

Comment: An explanation why `TrackingFunction` fails would also be appreciated, but I don't want to make this question too broad or unanswerable.

Answer (score 7):

I think it is a bug that `Manipulate` fails to interpret the input correctly if the parameter range contains at least one entry that is `NumericQ` but not `NumberQ`. In such a situation the default `TrackingFunction` is used instead of the specified one.

Another workaround is to provide the control in the form of a function, in which the second argument of `Dynamic` is used instead of `TrackingFunction`. In the following code this workaround is used to fix the behavior of the first `Manipulator`.

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{{a, b, c, d}, {lasta, lastb, lastc, lastd}}], 
 {a, 0, Pi, Manipulator[Dynamic[#, {lasta = a; &, a = #; &, a = #; &}]] &}, 
 {b, 0, N[Pi], TrackingFunction -> {lastb = b; &, b = #; &, b = #; &}}, 
 {c, 0, GoldenRatio, TrackingFunction -> {(Print["c"]; lastc = c); &, 
   (Print["c"]; c = #); &, (Print["c"]; c = #); &}},
 {{d, N[Pi]}, Pi, N[2. Pi], 0.1, Manipulator, 
   TrackingFunction -> {lastd = d; &, d = #; &, d = #; &}}, 
 {{lasta, 0}, None}, {{lastb, 0}, None}, {{lastc, 0}, None}, {{lastd, 0}, None}]
```