# TrackingFunction failure with Degree

Tags: bugs, manipulate, tracking

The following (simplified) code works as I intended:

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics[{Disk[{t, t^2}]}, PlotRange -> {0, 10}],
  {l, 0, 1, TrackingFunction -> (l = #; t = 0; &)},
  {t, 0, 3, ControlType -> Trigger}
]
```

The intent is that using the `l` control forces a reset on the `t` control.
(The actual use of the `l` control is not included in the example.)

However, when I change the 1 in the `l` control to be 1 "\[Degree]", (the Degree symbol), the Tracking Function fails to be invoked. Other expressions, such as 3/3 or x (when x has the value 1) work fine.

I am guessing that the problem has to do with code generated from the
`Manipulate`, but I haven't read anything that explains the difficulty to me. Does anyone have an explanation?

BTW, I am running v11.0.0.

Comment: Probably the same `NumericQ` but not `NumberQ` issue as in [this bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101669/18476).

Comment: Did you really use the string `"\[Degree]"` instead of the symbol `\[Degree]`?

Comment: I can reproduce this problem and it seems clearly to be the same bug as found previously by @Karsten7, so I tagging with 'bugs'.

Comment: Before submitting the question, I tried NumberQ and NumericQ and they both gave True. However, I mistakenly did NumberQ@1\[Degree] and NumericQ@1\[Degree]. I just reran the experiment using NumberQ[1\[Degree]] and NumericQ[1\[Degree]] and they indeed gave different answers.

Has the bug been reported?

Comment: The suggest fix (N[1\[Degree]]) indeed works. But the resultant label is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Karsten suggests it seems to be the numerics bug he discovered. A work around is to force numeric evaluation of the specification. That is, the following works.

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Disk[{t, t^2}]}, PlotRange -> {0, 10}], 
 {l, 0, N[°], TrackingFunction -> (l = #; t = 0; &)},
 {t, 0, 3, ControlType -> Trigger}]
```