# In Manipulate animation I can't have ResetButton and Play buttons

Tags: manipulate, animation, button, initialization

I want to add a separate reset button to this  code besides using the bookmark button (Ver:11.2). I've tried everything in

["Reset" Button for Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31344/reset-button-for-manipulate)

and elsewhere but ResetButton eliminates other buttons. Suggestions by Yves Klett and others work fine in there examples but fail when I add ResetButton to this code.

```
Manipulate[frames0[[g, i]], {{i, 1, "Frames"}, 1, nFrames, 1
  , AnimationRate -> 1000
  , Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open", AppearanceElements -> {"All"}}, 
  ImageSize -> Large
  , AnimationRunning -> True, 
  DefaultOptions -> {Animator -> AnimationRepetitions -> 1}
  }
 , {{g, 1, ""}
  , {1 -> " Demo1 ", 2 -> " Demo 2 "}
  , Appearance -> {"DialogBox"}}
 , Initialization :> {
   ClearAll["Global`*"];
   tt = 24;
   fPeriod = .1;
   timeTot = 27.9;
   nKs = 7; 
   imageSize = {800, 480};
   plotRange = {{0, 40}, {0, 25}};
   nFrames = Round[timeTot/fPeriod]*nKs;
   frames0 = {frames1, frames2};
   Module[{i, t},
    frames1 = 
      Flatten[Reap[
         Do[Sow[Table[
            Graphics[{Green, 
              Disk[{1.5*timeTot*(i - 1)/nKs + 1.5*t/nKs, 
                timeTot*(i - 1)/nKs + t/nKs}]}
             , ImageSize -> imageSize
             , PlotRange -> plotRange]
            , {t, 0, timeTot, fPeriod}]]
          , {i, 1, nKs}]][[2]]];],
   
   Module[{i, t},
    frames2 = 
     Flatten[Reap[
        Do[Sow[Table[
           Graphics[{Blue, 
             Disk[{1.5*timeTot*(i - 1)/nKs + 1.5*t/nKs, 
               timeTot*(i - 1)/nKs + t/nKs}]}
            , ImageSize -> imageSize
            , PlotRange -> plotRange]
            , {t, 0, timeTot, fPeriod}]]
         , {i, 1, nKs}]][[2]]]]
   }
 ]
```

Comment: replace `DefaultOptions -> {Animator -> AnimationRepetitions -> 1}` with `DefaultOptions -> {Animator -> {AppearanceElements -> {"PlayPauseButton", "ResetButton", "StepLeftButton",       "StepRightButton", "FasterSlowerButtons", "DirectionButton"},    AnimationRepetitions -> 1}}`?

Comment: if you wish you can also add a reset button next to `"ManipulateMenu"` button (+ button on top right) using `AppearanceElements -> {"ManipulateMenu", "ResetButton"}` before `Initialization :> ...`.

Comment: That works great. I see my mistake. I thought I had to use the {Animator -> AnimationRepetitions -> 1}. I think that was my last blockage. Thank you kglr!

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
DefaultOptions -> {Animator -> AnimationRepetitions -> 1}
```

with

```
DefaultOptions -> {Animator -> 
    {AppearanceElements -> 
      {"PlayPauseButton", "ResetButton", "StepLeftButton",       
       "StepRightButton", "FasterSlowerButtons", "DirectionButton"},    
     AnimationRepetitions -> 1}}
```

and, if you wish to add a reset button next to `"ManipulateMenu"` button (⊕ button on top right), insert

```
 AppearanceElements -> {"ManipulateMenu", "ResetButton"}
```

before `Initialization :> ...` to get

[image]